# Call hateoas actions/links in action of form with method post

Tags: html, angularjs, forms, action, hateoas

We are using `hateoas` to call backend our links. Our HateoasWrapper looks like this (copied out from browser console):

```
{
    $actions: [
        {
            $call: function ()
            action: "load"
            href: "http://myApi"
            method: "POST"
            rel: "parent"
        }
    ],
    $load: function (),
    Links: [
        {
            ActionValue: "load"
            Href: "http://myApi"
            Methid: "POST"
            Reld: "parent"
        }
    ]
}
```

So we can call simply our links like this: `myObject.$load()` (it calls the href from load). This works fine.

Now I try to call the `$load()` in the `action` of a `form` element. For this I put the call in the `action` and fire it with a `submit` like this:

```
<form action="ctrl.myObject.$load()" method="post" target="_blank">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

This doesnt work. It opens a new tab, but with this error: `Cannot post/ctrl.myObject.$load()`

When I put the href hardcoded into the action, it works (new tab with correct data):

```
<form action="http://myApi" method="post" target="_blank">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Is it possible to call an `hateoas` `action` in a `form` like my solution?

Comment: Try changing your action method to action="ctrl.myObject.Links[0].Href"

Comment: This could work, but there are more than one link and I would like to call it with the actionValue name $[ActionValue], because the order of the list is also dynamic (if this is clear).

Comment: If there are more than one link, how will you know for which action, which link to use?

Comment: @Vivz When you take a look on the hatoeasWrapper in my question: There are some links in the $actions. This links have a href and a action value. This actions generate a function like the $load() in the wrapper. And if you call obj.$load(), hateoas goes through the $actions, searches the object, which contains the name of the function in the actionValue and calls it's href. So I havn't to use the href I can just call the $load() function and it solves it with hatoeas for me.

Comment: Please update your question with the definition of `$load()`.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the interpolation here. Since `action` is not a standard AngularJS directive/attribute, the passed expression cannot be understood by AngularJS engine.

Try wrapping the expression `ctrl.myObject.$load()` in curly braces like `{{ctrl.myObject.$load()}}`, and then AngularJS will automatically replace it with the returned value of the function.

Observe it in action in the following snippet. Open the inspection panel and observe what's in the form's `action` attribute.

```js
angular.module("myapp", [])
  .controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.myaction = function() {
      return "abc";
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<form action="{{myaction()}}">
  Inspect this form's action in console
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: @MrBuggy -- Can you show me the definition of `$load` function?